# How to simulate C-style "ifdef" macro in QML?

Tags: qt, macros, qml, qt5

I need to switch off some parts of QML code, because this code has been done for demo purposes and it will be removed in final release. But the product will be used with these demo features for long, so I can't use a separate branch with demo features and constantly merge all new features to that branch - it's just not convenient. So it'd be nice to have this code running but easy to switch off and/or remove when needed. In C and C++ I use `ifdef` macro for that, but is it possible to do the same in QML?

Comment: Place your code in `Component` and so use needed component.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As @Mark suggested, context properties can be used in QML to decide in run time if some macro is enabled or not, but the example he provides does not address the case, when you need to instantiate an object based on this decision, but only covers case when inside a code block. So I will provide the full example of what I did.

In my case I exposed a class to QML only when a macro was defined during compile time:

**main.cpp**:

```
#ifdef SMTP_SUPPORT
qmlRegisterType<SmtpClientHelper>("com.some.plugin", 1, 0, "SmtpClient");
engine.rootContext()->setContextProperty("SMTP_SUPPORT", QVariant(true));
#else
engine.rootContext()->setContextProperty("SMTP_SUPPORT", QVariant(false));
#endif // SMTP_SUPPORT
```

Then on QML side I check this macro and decide if SmtpClient object must be created:

**qml**:

```
import QtQuick 2.0;
import com.some.plugin 1.0

Item {
    id: root
    // ...

    property var smtpClient // No inside any function, need to instantiate the object

    Component.onCompleted: {
        if (SMTP_SUPPORT) {
            smtpClient = Qt.createQmlObject('                                                 \
                import QtQuick 2.0;                                                           \
                import com.some.plugin 1.0;                                                   \
                SmtpClient {                                                                  \
                    id: smtpClient;                                                           \
                                                                                              \
                    function setSenderEmail(email) {                                          \
                        senderEmail = email;                                                  \
                        storage.save("common", "clientEmail", email);                         \
                    }                                                                         \
                }                                                                             \
            ', root, "SmtpClient");
        }
    }

    // Reference smtpClient normally, like if it was statically created
    TextInput {
        id: senderEmailLogin
        anchors.fill: parent
        font.pixelSize: Globals.defaultFontSize
        text: smtpClient ? smtpClient.senderEmail : ""
        onEditingFinished: if (smtpClient) smtpClient.setSenderEmail(text)
        activeFocusOnPress: true
    }
}
```

I think Loader should also do the job, so you could create a separate component, reference it in Loader's `source` or `sourceComponent` properties if C++ macro is defined, but I am not sure, because not sure if this component will be statically checked if (in my case) `SmtpClient` type is available

Comment: I know this is the *right* solution, but it is also a *terrible* solution. It is absurd that in order to effect a bog-standard time-tested precompiler behavior, we have to use text strings to start implementing whole components and features. Ridiculous. This breaks all the IDE tools, dramatically increasing the likelihood of coding bugs as well as generally making the code much harder to support. +1 to your answer, -1 to Qt.

Answer (score 4):

If you can refactor those parts into their own components, you have two options:

1. [File selectors](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qqmlfileselector.html)
2. [Loader](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-loader.html)

The first option is perhaps a bit closer to a C-style `#ifdef` macro than using `Loader`, as it works at the file level. As long as you don't overuse `Loader`, though (e.g. as a delegate in a large view), they should both do the job fine.

Comment: thanks for the answer. These two options do a different thing. I don't have (and can't really make) separate components either a file or a piece of code that I can load dynamically. I rather have scattered pieces of code here and there that introduce a couple of properties, change some functions' flow, make use of `Component.onCompleted` etc, so both ways are not really helpful unless I duplicate some qml files that will be 90% identical, which seems an overkill to me.

Comment: I think you're out of luck then, unfortunately.

Comment: See https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qtquickcontrols2-fileselectors.html for explanation of using file selectors in QML. There are a few default selectors for style, locale, platform etc. but you can also define your own and enable them from C++ or environment variable (see https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qfileselector.html) .

Comment: If you want to either include or omit a specific QML Item using file selectors, you might be able to move it into a component where the real implementation is selected with a file selector and the default or alternative version is empty just a dummy `Item {}`? Haven't tried this specifically yet though.

Answer (score 4):

It's not the same as an #ifdef because the decision making all happens at runtime, but I sometimes use this approach, which gives a similar usage pattern.

**main.cpp**

```
    QQmlApplicationEngine engine;
#ifdef DEMO_MODE
    engine.rootContext()->setContextProperty("DEMO_MODE", QVariant(true));
#else
    engine.rootContext()->setContextProperty("DEMO_MODE", QVariant(false));
#endif
    engine.load(QUrl("qrc:/ui/MainQmlFile.qml"));
```

**then, from any .qml file in the project**

```
if (DEMO_MODE) {

} else {

}
```

Answer (score 2):

`#ifdef` is a preprocessor instructions, i.e. something processed at build time before the C or C++ compiler gets to see the code.
You could do the same using your text manipulation language of choice, processing the QML files at build time before they get processed e.g. by the Qt resource compiler.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use class DebugC with function

```
Q_INVOKABLE bool isDebuggingEnable()
{
  #ifdef QT_DEBUG
    return true;
  #else
    return false;
  #endif
}
```

and then register this class in qml

```
viewer->rootContext()->setContextProperty("stName", DebugCObj)
```

now you can easily call stName.isDebuggingEnable() method for checking debugging is enable or not in your QML file. its just a trick

Comment: thank you for the answer. I have 2 comments - it's better to use `QT_NO_DEBUG` or `QT_DEBUG` macros to check whether project is compiled in debug/release mode, rather than invent a new one. Second, this will work like plain `if` not like macros like `ifdef` in C, which is somewhat different.

Answer (score 0):

QML is not *compiled* but *interpreted* at run time, so *preprocessor* directives can't be used *directly* by QML.
But this is not a limitation,  because it is possible to introduce properties to QML from c++ side, Thus directives can be placed on the C++ side to staff those properties, while decision making based on those properties, normal `if/then`,  with Javascript can be used in QML side.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to some of the other answers here (dynamically adding QML code from javascript based on a property, or using file selectors), another approach that may work if what you want is to have different QML component implementations, or disable a QML component, based on a compile time condition or setting, is to configure CMake to include alternate QML files at build time, and set `QML_RESOURCE_ALIAS` to the desired QML component name (as referenced by other QML files) in the built executable's resources.   For example:

1. Create two versions of a QML component, e.g. `MyComponent_enabled.qml` which defines a component and `MyComponent_disabled.qml` which is an empty item (just `import QtQuick ; Item {}`.)
2. In CMakeLists, choose which one to use.  E.g.

```
option(ENABLE_MY_COMPONENT "Enable MyComponent")
if(ENABLE_MY_COMPONENT)
  set(MYCOMPONENT_QML_FILE MyComponent_enabled.qml)
else()
  set(MYCOMPONENT_QML_FILE MyComponent_disabled.qml)
endif()
set_source_file_properties(${MYCOMPONENT_QML_FILE} PROPERTIES QT_RESOURCE_ALIAS MyComponent.qml)
qml_add_qml_module(yourapp
  ... other stuff ...
  QML_FILES
    ... other QML files ...
    ${MYCOMPONENT_QML_FILE}
  ...
)
```

3. Use `MyComponent {...}` to instantiate `MyComponent` in other QML files.

(This will of course baffle QtCreator a bit -- it will only show one or the other QML file in the file list etc.  There may be ways to get QtCreator or other IDEs to know about both files but that's another topic.)